# Kruskal-Wallis and Negative binomial regression do not agree

Tags: count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, kruskal-wallis-test

I am comparing the number of broods made by dung beetles (`Brood_Number`) across three temperature treatments (`Temp_Offset`, a 3 level factor (+0 deg, +2 deg and +4 deg)). I have run the following negative binomial model:

```
    m=glm.nb(Brood_Number~Temp_offset, data=Trial2)
```

Which gives me:

```
    Call:
    glm.nb(formula = Brood_Number ~ Temp_offset, data = Trial2, init.theta = 7.152501499, 
link = log)

    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -2.6469  -0.9302   0.1293   0.5589   1.4051  

    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)    3.4247     0.1569  21.825  < 2e-16 ***
    Temp_offset2  -0.6138     0.2228  -2.756  0.00586 ** 
    Temp_offset3  -0.2210     0.2172  -1.017  0.30900    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(7.1525) family taken to be 1)

        Null deviance: 32.663  on 22  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance: 24.939  on 20  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 177.33

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


                  Theta:  7.15 
              Std. Err.:  2.92 

     2 x log-likelihood:  -169.326 
    >
```

Comparing the model with and without the `Temp_Offset` term improves model fit. I have interpreted this as saying that `Temp_Offset` significantly affects brood number, but that there is only a significant difference between the base level (+0 deg) and the +2 deg treatment. There is no difference between the base level and the +4 deg treatment.

I then performed a Kruskal-Wallis test:

```
    kruskal.test(Brood_Number~Temp_offset, data=Trial2)
```

Which gives me:

```
            Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

   data:  Brood_Number by Temp_offset
   Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 5.1272, df = 2, p-value = 0.07703
```

So the Kruskal-Wallis and the NB regression give different answers. I feel that the NB regression is the one to be trusted because NB specifically models overdispersed count data (which I have). Am I correct in trusting the significant effect of temperature from the negative binomial regression instead of the non-significant Kruskal-Wallis? I can see no advantage in the KW test. (It was suggested that I try it by a reviewer ...)

Raw data are as follows. The response is the number of broods. The independent factor is the temperature offset. Brood numbers for the different temperature treatments are (its a small data set):

Brood numbers:

```
    +0 deg: 32, 47, 19, 23, 16, 45, 33

    +2 deg: 21, 12, 3, 22, 20, 6, 29, 20

    +4 deg: 16, 31, 14, 24, 30, 26, 40, 16
```

Thanks

Comment: No mystery here: Assuming a negative binomial model provides information. The KW test does not use that information.

Comment: @BruceETCould you please clarify your comment? Do you mean that a NB uses additional info that the KW does not?

Comment: any chance you can post your original data?  It would make for a more complete/satisfying answer ...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264646/should-there-be-agreement-between-nb-glm-and-kruskal-wallis-for-categorical-vari?rq=1 ?

Comment: @BenBolker It did look at that question, but its a little different to mine because that question was comparing a NB with a factor plus covariates, with just a KW (with one factor). My KW and NB both only have one factor. I will post the data :)

Comment: @BenBolker Data posted. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for data. For what it's worth: Confirmed K-W as posted. Standard one-factor ANOVA has P-value 0.041, Welch t between 0 and 2 degrees has P-val 0.028. So there are borderline suggestions of 5% significance there. (Neither 'Welchified' one-factor ANOVA nor std ANOVA on ranks is signif at 5%.)  QQ plot of residuals from std ANOVA doesn't really look normal; not sure whether NB assumption may be the cure for that. Feels sort of  like I'm 'shopping around' for a method of analysis that gives P-value barely below 5%. Uncomfortable with that.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my data! I am so grateful! Can I look for post hoc differences between treatments? Would it be better to use eemeans (lsmeans) packages to look for differences between treatments rather than looking at the parameter estimates (as I have done above)?

Comment: parameter estimates are fine but give you only a specified set of contrasts. I'm not overly enthusiastic about post-hoc differences (you know there's a significant pattern overall, you know that +2 is lower than +0 and that +0 and +4 are about the same; what do you really need more p-values for?) but you could use `pairs()` in emmeans to do the pairwise contrasts. (Note that doing post hoc contrasts properly will involve multiple comparisons corrections, which may further weaken your evidence ...)

Comment: @BruceET Thanks so much for your thoughts. I agree, I dont like shopping around either. But Im pretty satisfied now that the NB was the way to go

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for your thoughts. I am only interested in comparisons to the baseline level, but do take your point about not getting too caught up in post hoc tests. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### take-home messages

- The negative binomial uses more information from the data, so it's expected that it would be slightly more powerful than the rank-based Kruskal-Wallis test. In general, you'd use K-W if you were concerned  that the distributional assumptions of your model were badly violated.
- The difference between $p=0.021$ (overall significance of the NB model; see below) and $p=0.077$ is not enormous; they do lie on opposite sides of the "magic" $p=0.05$ line, but we wouldn't necessarily say the tests disagree strongly about the strength of evidence against the null hypothesis.
- The diagnostic plots for the NB suggest that the negative binomial model is entirely defensible in this case.
- You should probably focus on the overall test of significance (see `drop1()` below) rather than stating the significance of the two differences (+0 vs +2 and +0 vs +4) separately; report the overall $p$-value, then state the actual group values (e.g. 30.7, 16.6, 24.6, from `emmeans::emmeans(m, ~Temp_offset, type="response")`)
- try to avoid statements like "there is no difference between the base level and the +4 deg treatment" - I know you meant "no *significant* difference", but it's a slippery slope to fooling yourself that the two outcomes are actually identical, rather than just that you can't see a clear difference between them ...

#### details

Data:

```
Trial2 <- data.frame(Brood_Number=c(
                 32, 47, 19, 23, 16, 45, 33, ## +0 deg
                 21, 12, 3,  22, 20, 6,  29, 20, ## +2 deg
                 16, 31, 14, 24, 30, 26, 40, 16), ## +4 deg
                 Temp_offset=rep(c("+0 deg","+2 deg", "+4 deg"), c(7,8,8)))
## generate rank information
Trial2$Brood_rank <- rank(Trial2$Brood_Number)
```

Compare raw values to ranked values. The Kruskal-Wallis is similar to an ANOVA on the ranks (in this case `anova(lm(Brood_rank ~Temp_offset, data=Trial2))` gives $p=0.070$, pretty close to the K-W value.)

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
Trial2B <- tidyr::gather(Trial2,var_type,value,-Temp_offset)
ggplot(Trial2B, aes(Temp_offset, value))+geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~var_type,scale="free")
```

[image]

You can see that taking ranks pulls in the extreme values slightly, bringing the groups closer together and decreasing the strength of evidence for among-group differences.

Fit the model:

```
m <- MASS::glm.nb(Brood_Number~Temp_offset, data=Trial2)
```

Run tests:

```
drop1(m, test="Chisq")  ## p=0.021
kruskal.test(Brood_Number~Temp_offset, data=Trial2) ## p=0.077
```

Diagnostics:

(1) base R

```
png("nbplot1.png")
op <- par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(2,3,2,1),las=1, mgp=c(1,0.5,0))
plot(m)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]

(i) The residuals vs fitted plot looks OK, but it more or less has to (since there is no possibility for nonlinearity in a one-way categorical design); (ii) the Q-Q plot looks good, so little evidence for distributional differences; (iii) scale-location ditto - little evidence for heteroscedasticity; (iv) nothing that looks like an outlier or influential point.

An alternative set of diagnostics (using simulation-based residuals and among other things performing a significance test on the deviation of the distribution)

(2) `DHARMa` package

```
png("nbplot2.png")
DHARMa::simulateResiduals(m,plot=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

[image]